# Trying to create a cos(x) calculating function

Tags: c++, factorial

I am coding a `cos(x)` function in C++ but the result I am getting is infinity, except that it should be `-1/3`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
```

The factorial function:

```
int factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned long factorial = 1;

    for(int o=1;o<=n;o++)
    {
        factorial *= o;
    }
}
int main()
{
    double x;
    double answre;
    double input;

    cin>>input;

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        double y=2*(i)+2;
```

I declared `y` here instead of implementing it's value directly, since I thought it is dividing by factorial instantaneously and that is the reason for all the parentheses as well.

```
        x=((pow(input,2*(i)+2))/(factorial(y)))*(pow(-1,(i)+1));

        x=+x;    
    }

    answere=1+x;

    cout<<answere<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Error:** Identifer "*answere*" is undefined...

Comment: Try printing the results of a few calls to your `factorial` function. It doesn't take much to get the calculation to overflow.

Comment: You are not returning anything in factorial

Comment: Did your compiler not warn you about not returning anything from function *`factorial()`*? Also, don't break code into three parts (use comments if you want to write anything in the code), it makes reading it difficult...

Comment: x = ... ; x+=x; mb it should be answer += x; ?

Comment: Don't EVER use factorial in anything useful in C++! Unless you absolutely know what you're doing. It can very easily blow up and overflow. You want to calculate a cosine? Use a Taylor expansion or some other expansion.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist -- doesn't the Taylor series use factorials?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist This code _is_ the Taylor series expansion (using the first two terms) if I'm not completely off...

Comment: @PeteBecker - yes, the Taylor's series for cosine is expressed using factorials.   That doesn't mean it is necessary to calculate the factorial directly.

Comment: I mean, if you want to calculate a cosine, the "real" way is usually range reduction + a polynomial approximation.

Comment: thanks for all the answers .The problem was that x+=x gives a wrong answer since x will be already declared:(x=(-2)+(-2)),while i wanted something like that:(x=0+(-2)) as a start.Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning anything in factorial

Comment: sorry,i forgot and thanks but even after returning factorial,the sum is 1.6 bar which is wrong.But thanks for the help

Comment: First time seeing a *comment* **directly** becoming an *answer*...

Answer (score 0):

```
    x=((pow(input,2*(i)+2))/(factorial(y)))*(pow(-1,(i)+1));

    x=+x; // ???
```

If you want to add to `x`, just write `x += ...`. What you did was *assign* one (!) summand to `x` and then set `x` to itself. You are never adding anything.